# Как можно рисовать кольца в google maps на android (java)?

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api

Есть объект `GoogleMap`, находящийся в `MapView` и задача рисовать в нем кольца с некоторой прозрачностью. Причем кольца должны быть построены по метрам.

Можно представить нужный объект как два `Circle` с одним `LatLng` с разными радиусами (которые задаются в метрах) и закрашенной областью между этими кругами областью. Рисование circle с изменением размера и цвета контура не подходит по понятным причинам.

Смотрю в сторону наземных наложений `GroundOverlay`. Действительно ли нет других вариантов?

Comment: Как на счёт рекомендаций API? [ссылка](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays) (а ещё лучше - [ссылка](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/shapes))

Comment: Первая ссылка про Веб, что немного не то (хотя там тоже нет рекомендаций, как рисовать необходимые мне кольца, а не обычные круги). Рекомендацию API android я читал и нашел решение только в [GroundOverlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/groundoverlay?hl=en)